# Moving Mouse in Python on VM

Tags: python

I am trying to move my mouse using this simple code.

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(10,10)
```

My machine is running MacOS, and I run a Virtual Machine on my computer with windows 7. When I run this code on my Virtual Machine, it doesnt move the actual mouse, but rather uses a "ghost mouse" to make the click. When I try to use this code to make the mouse move on a windows desktop machine, you can see the cursor moving (unlike on my VM).

Are there any ideas to making the actual mouse cursor move on my virtual machine through python?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would the VM be able to override the host's mouse location?

Comment: Because this is programming and I want it to. Its possible that its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, I don't really believe it's possible. For all the VM knows, the host doesn't really even exist (for the most part). One major thing VMs do is sandbox the client from the host. (See [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9011/does-a-virtual-machine-stop-malware-from-doing-harm)).

The other thing is, that would be a massive security issue. If I had access to your machine from the VM, then I could ostensibly click through and install malware.

Now for the catch: You probably can.

VMS can communicate to their host through the network, so if you had a server listening on the host for the communication, and the host moves the cursor after reading the comms, then yes. Note that this method requires explicitly setting up the host to listen to the client. No method I am aware of allows the VM to directly interact with the host without the host "listening".

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the correct response. Its weird because the program I am trying to click on doesnt seem to respond to clicks unless the actual host mouse is moved. Python can move a "ghost mouse" within my vm over the button, and I see the host mouse (which is unmoved, yet its cursor changes to a button press, an index finger). However when Python clicks nothing happens. I assume the program I am trying to click on has some security check that the actual host mouse is in the bounds of the button its clicking on (possibly to prevent malware)